# Is there a way to collect if?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a way to delete_if data:

```
Article.all.delete_if { |a| a.type != "Swimming"}
```

I was wondering if there is a similar way to "collect if" date ?

Comment: collect_if = select

Answer (score 4):

Have you had a look at the `Array#collect` and `Array#select` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Like this works:

```
matching_articles = magazines.collect { |m| m.articles.where("type != 'Swimming'") }.flatten
```